# getting error in cloud firestore permission

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

getting error in cloud firestore my image is not storing in firebase the screen is not displaying

> [VERBOSE-2:dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception:
> [cloud_firestore/permission-denied] The caller does not have
> permission to execute the specified operation.
> #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
> #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:315:18)
>
> #2      MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:518:43)
>
> #3      MethodChannelDocumentReference.get (package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_document_reference.dart:69:42)
>
> #4      _JsonDocumentReference.get (package:cloud_firestore/src/document_reference.dart:146:7)
>
> #5      _HomePageState.getArrLength (package:marcjrfoundation/pages/home/home.dart:341:33) 
> #6      _HomePageState.notifyUser (package:marcjrfoundation/pages/home/home.dart:111:<…>

security rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the actual code that triggers the error message against these rules, it is impossible to say more than the error message itself does: apparently your app doesn't have a signed in user when it calls Firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your rules for cloud firestore as well firebase Storage like this.

//firestore

```
 allow read, write: if true;
```

//firebase Storage

```
allow read, write: if true;
```

in my case, I changed both rules now working fine everything. try it maybe its help you

Comment: This is really really bad thing to do! This disables every security and will allow everyone to manipulate any document.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before

On September 19, a major change to Cloud Storage for Firebase was finalized where each Firebase project will now have its own dedicated storage service account, resulting in improved security.

check this [link](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq#storage-accounts) for more info

and I called this API Solved my problem
I tried this

```
POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v1beta/{bucket=projects/*/buckets/*}:addFirebase
```

From [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/storage/rest/v1beta/projects.buckets/addFirebase)
it took a minutes and it work the firebase storage Roles finally applied ,